# Subdivision modification issue

Tags: subdivision-surface

Sorry am asking away from home, so no pictures. But here's the deal.After using subdivision surface modifier, I can't sculpt the object when I switch back to edit mode, you'd still see the mesh covering the subdivided object. What do I do? Cause it seems that the subdivision doesn't actually help or work if I can't sculpt after that

Comment: Thanks man, I don't usually apply it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're using the modifier but not applying it. If you click "Apply" on the subdivision surface modifier, it'll apply the modifier to the mesh and you should be able to see the difference in edit mode; after